# Problem in Radio button in IE7?

Tags: visualforce

When I use apex:selectRadio on VF page it works fine in chrome but when I use IE7 there is space gets increased between button and option name. Any one suggest Reason ?

Comment: Are you using any custom CSS and/or HTML? Could you post your page code please?

Comment: try to insert extra `margin:0; padding:0;` ?

Comment: ^^As mast0r said, trying changing the css margin and padding values. I have run into issues with this working with IE9 which begs the question..."Why IE7????"

Answer (score 1):

Without your visualforce page it's hard to tell if it's something your doing or whether this is an issue with the standard Salesforce CSS.

In any event you can use the styleClass attribute to add a CSS class that you can use to override the standard behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I can think of is that IE7 is outdated and shouldn't be used. True, this isn't a proper answer but the only way we can force people to stop using old browsers is to stop supporting them.

Yes some IT departments mandate the use of an old browser, but that's no excuse—they should be fixing whatever requires an old browser not expecting everybody else to keep pandering to them.